# Magento: Change order of blocks in left column

Tags: xml, magento, magento-1.7

I am running into a frustrating issue in changing the order of blocks in the left column in Magento.  There are three blocks that I would like to display in the left column in the following order:

1) A block titled block_left_top
2) A block titled block_left_social_icons
3) The compare products block that is traditionally in the right column

In my local.xml file, I have done the following:

To move compare out of the right column

```
<reference name="right"><action method="unsetChild"><name>catalog.compare.sidebar</name></action></reference>
```

To add the two static blocks to the left column and insert the compare item into the left column

```
    <reference name="left">

 <block type="cms/block" name="block_left_top" ><action method="setBlockId"><block_id>block_left_top</block_id></action></block>

<block type="cms/block" name="block_left_social_icons" ><action method="setBlockId"><block_id>block_left_social_icons</block_id></action></block>

<action method="insert"><name>catalog.compare.sidebar</name></action>

</reference>
```

This is working great with one MAJOR problem.  No matter what I do, the Compare sidebar shows up first, instead of last which is what I want.  I've tried using the before/after attributes, but these have the effect of moving the blocks outside of the left column entirely.

Does anyone have any insights?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Either

```
<block type="catalog/product_compare_sidebar" after="block_left_social_icons" name="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml"/>
```

Or

```
<block type="catalog/product_compare_sidebar" after="-" name="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml"/>
```

Tried something like this?

Comment: Yes, but that had the effect of putting the compare block below the left column's closing div tag, instead of within it.

Comment: Can you check if the left closing div is being closed early in social_icons or something like that. It won't put it outside of the left div unless the tags are closed prematurely. Atleast it shouldn't